# PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'decimal.Decimal'>: it's not the same object as decimal.Decimal

Tags: python, django, pickle

This is the error I got today at <a href"http://filmaster.com">filmaster.com:

> ```py
> PicklingError: Can't pickle <class
> 'decimal.Decimal'>: it's not the same
> object as decimal.Decimal
> ```

What does that exactly mean? It does not seem to be making a lot of sense...
It seems to be connected with django caching. You can see the whole traceback here:

> ```py
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
>  File
> "/home/filmaster/django-trunk/django/core/handlers/base.py",
> line 92, in get_response    response =
> callback(request, *callback_args,
> **callback_kwargs)
>
>  File
> "/home/filmaster/film20/film20/core/film_views.py",
> line 193, in show_film   
> workflow.set_data_for_authenticated_user()
>
>  File
> "/home/filmaster/film20/film20/core/film_views.py",
> line 518, in
> set_data_for_authenticated_user   
> object_id = self.the_film.parent.id)
>
>  File
> "/home/filmaster/film20/film20/core/film_helper.py",
> line 179, in get_others_ratings   
> set_cache(CACHE_OTHERS_RATINGS,
> str(object_id) + "_" + str(user_id),
> userratings)
>
>  File
> "/home/filmaster/film20/film20/utils/cache_helper.py",
> line 80, in set_cache    return
> cache.set(CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX
> + full_path, result, get_time(cache_string))
>
>  File
> "/home/filmaster/django-trunk/django/core/cache/backends/memcached.py",
> line 37, in set   
> self._cache.set(smart_str(key), value,
> timeout or self.default_timeout)
>
>  File
> "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/cmemcache.py",
> line 128, in set    val, flags =
> self._convert(val)
>
>  File
> "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/cmemcache.py",
> line 112, in _convert    val =
> pickle.dumps(val, 2)
>
> PicklingError: Can't pickle <class
> 'decimal.Decimal'>: it's not the same
> object as decimal.Decimal
> ```

And the source code for Filmaster can be downloaded from here: [bitbucket.org/filmaster/filmaster-test](http://bitbucket.org/filmaster/filmaster-test/)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've gotten a similar error after writing an erroneous __getstate__ method for an object to change its pickle behavior. Not sure what the issue is but check for any of those.

Comment: I've also seen this with class decorators, specifically the six.add_metaclass

Answer (score 119):

I got this error when running in an jupyter notebook. I think the problem was that I was using `%load_ext autoreload` `autoreload 2`. Restarting my kernel and rerunning solved the problem.

Comment: It seems that altering a class method is the cause of the problem. My guess is that the `autoreload` isn't updating a definition saved somewhere else. Restarting would fix it because the newer definition is loaded in both places.

Comment: Is there any other workaround for this scenario **without** restarting the kernel (which kind of beats the purpose of the `autoreload` extension..)

Comment: @Stav it would indeed beat the purpose of `autoreload`, which is to reload a module without erasing the values tied to this module which are loaded in memory

Comment: Didn't expect to see this here, let alone have it be the solution.  But it was.  Thank you!

Answer (score 39):

One oddity of Pickle is that the way you import a class before you pickle one of it's instances can subtly change the pickled object. Pickle requires you to have imported the object identically both before you pickle it and before you unpickle it.

So for example:

```
from a.b import c
C = c()
pickler.dump(C)
```

will make a subtly different object (sometimes) to:

```
from a import b
C = b.c()
pickler.dump(C)
```

Try fiddling with your imports, it might correct the problem.

Comment: so how come this pickling issue only occurs once in thousands of requests and normally it works just fine?

Answer (score 29):

I will demonstrate the problem with simple Python classes in Python2.7:

```
In [13]: class A: pass  
In [14]: class B: pass

In [15]: A
Out[15]: <class __main__.A at 0x7f4089235738>

In [16]: B
Out[16]: <class __main__.B at 0x7f408939eb48>

In [17]: A.__name__ = "B"

In [18]: pickle.dumps(A)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PicklingError: Can't pickle <class __main__.B at 0x7f4089235738>: it's not the same object as __main__.B
```

This error is shown because we are trying to dump A, but because we changed its name to refer to another object "B", pickle is actually confused with which object to dump - class A or B. Apparently, pickle guys are very smart and they have already put a check on this behavior.

**Solution**:
Check if the object you are trying to dump has conflicting name with another object.

I have demonstrated debugging for the case presented above with ipython and ipdb below:

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <class __main__.B at 0x7f4089235738>: it's not the same object as __main__.B

In [19]: debug
> /<path to pickle dir>/pickle.py(789)save_global()
    787                 raise PicklingError(
    788                     "Can't pickle %r: it's not the same object as %s.%s" %
--> 789                     (obj, module, name))
    790
    791         if self.proto >= 2:

ipdb> pp (obj, module, name)               **<------------- you are trying to dump obj which is class A from the pickle.dumps(A) call.**
(<class __main__.B at 0x7f4089235738>, '__main__', 'B')
ipdb> getattr(sys.modules[module], name)   **<------------- this is the conflicting definition in the module (__main__ here) with same name ('B' here).**
<class __main__.B at 0x7f408939eb48>
```

I hope this saves some headaches! Adios!!

Answer (score 14):

I can't explain why this is failing either, but my own solution to fix this was to change all my code from doing

```
from point import Point
```

to

```
import point
```

this one change and it worked. I'd love to know why... hth

Comment: This helped me as well and I would love to know why!

Comment: Any updates on why it works? My guess is that import XX reload everything, from XX import XXX only reload a specific module or function.

Answer (score 9):

Did you somehow `reload(decimal)`, or monkeypatch the decimal module to change the Decimal class? These are the two things most likely to produce such a problem.

Answer (score 9):

There can be issues starting a process with `multiprocessing` by calling `__init__`. Here's a demo:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class SubProcClass:
    def __init__(self, pipe, startloop=False):
        self.pipe = pipe
        if startloop:
            self.do_loop()

    def do_loop(self):
        while True:
            req = self.pipe.recv()
            self.pipe.send(req * req)

class ProcessInitTest:
    def __init__(self, spawn=False):
        if spawn:
            mp.set_start_method('spawn')
        (self.msg_pipe_child, self.msg_pipe_parent) = mp.Pipe(duplex=True)

    def start_process(self):
        subproc = SubProcClass(self.msg_pipe_child)
        self.trig_proc = mp.Process(target=subproc.do_loop, args=())
        self.trig_proc.daemon = True
        self.trig_proc.start()

    def start_process_fail(self):
        self.trig_proc = mp.Process(target=SubProcClass.__init__, args=(self.msg_pipe_child,))
        self.trig_proc.daemon = True
        self.trig_proc.start()

    def do_square(self, num):
        # Note: this is an synchronous usage of mp,
        # which doesn't make sense. But this is just for demo
        self.msg_pipe_parent.send(num)
        msg = self.msg_pipe_parent.recv()
        print('{}^2 = {}'.format(num, msg))
```

Now, with the above code, if we run this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = ProcessInitTest(spawn=True)
    t.start_process_fail()
    for i in range(1000):
        t.do_square(i)
```

We get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "start_class_process1.py", line 40, in <module>
    t.start_process_fail()
  File "start_class_process1.py", line 29, in start_process_fail
    self.trig_proc.start()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/context.py", line 212, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/context.py", line 274, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py", line 33, in __init__
    super().__init__(process_obj)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 21, in __init__
    self._launch(process_obj)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py", line 48, in _launch
    reduction.dump(process_obj, fp)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 59, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function SubProcClass.__init__ at 0x10073e510>: it's not the same object as __main__.__init__
```

And if we change it to use `fork` instead of `spawn`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = ProcessInitTest(spawn=False)
    t.start_process_fail()
    for i in range(1000):
        t.do_square(i)
```

We get this error:

```
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/process.py", line 254, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pipe'
```

But if we call the `start_process` method, which doesn't call `__init__` in the `mp.Process` target, like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = ProcessInitTest(spawn=False)
    t.start_process()
    for i in range(1000):
        t.do_square(i)
```

It works as expected (whether we use `spawn` or `fork`).

Comment: Thanks for the deep dive on this. I'm using an mp Pool and running on windows (hence spawn is only option unfortunately). Something screwy is going on with the mp module! Out of thousands of equivalent tasks, I get this pickling error on just the last dozen or so, while all others execute just fine. My work-around was to pickle `obj.__dict__` rather than `obj`, which oddly enough works

Answer (score 4):

Same happened to me

Restarting the kernel worked for me

Comment: Yes, restarting the kernel did solve the problem for me as well. Thanks for mentioning :)

Answer (score 2):

Due to the restrictions based upon reputation I cannot comment, but the answer of [Salim Fahedy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1413299/11567151) and following the debugging-path set me up to identify a cause for this error, even when using `dill` instead of `pickle`:
Under the hood, `dill` also accesses some functions of `dill`. And in `pickle._Pickler.save_global()` there is an `import` happening. To me it seems, that this is more of a "hack" than a real solution as this method fails as soon as the class of the instance you are trying to pickle is not imported from the lowest level of the package the class is in. Sorry for the bad explanation, maybe examples are more suitable:

The following example would fail:

```
from oemof import solph

...
(some code here, giving you the object 'es')
...

model = solph.Model(es)
pickle.dump(model, open('file.pickle', 'wb))
```

It fails, because while you can use `solph.Model`, the class actually is `oemof.solph.models.Model` for example. The `save_global()` resolves that (or some function before that which passes it to `save_global()`), but then imports `Model` from `oemof.solph.models` and throws an error, because it's not the same import as `from oemof import solph.Model` (or something like that, I'm not 100% sure about the workings).

The following example would work:

```
from oemof.solph.models import Model

...
some code here, giving you the object 'es')
...

model = Model(es)
pickle.dump(model, open('file.pickle', 'wb'))
```

It works, because now the `Model` object is imported from the same place, the `pickle._Pickler.save_global()` imports the comparison object (`obj2`) from.

**Long story short**: When pickling an object, make sure to import the class from the lowest possible level.

**Addition**: This also seems to apply to objects stored in the attributes of the class-instance you want to pickle. If for example `model` had an attribute `es` that itself is an object of the class `oemof.solph.energysystems.EnergySystem`, we would need to import it as:

```
from oemof.solph.energysystems import EnergySystem

es = EnergySystem()
```

Comment: Great answer, well explained.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem while debugging (Spyder). Everything worked normally if run the program. But, if I start to debug I faced the picklingError.

But, once I chose the option **Execute in dedicated console** in Run configuration per file (short-cut: ctrl+F6) everything worked normally as expected. I do not know exactly how it is adapting.

Note: In my script I have many imports like

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
import os, sys, re, math
```

My basic understanding was, because of star (*) I was getting this picklingError.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I had a function with the same name defined twice in a file. So I guess it was confused about which one it was trying to pickle.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem that no one has mentioned yet. I have a package with a `__init__` file that does, among other things:

```
from .mymodule import cls
```

Then my top-level code says:

```
import mypkg
obj = mypkg.cls()
```

The problem with this is that in my top-level code, the type appears to be `mypkg.cls`, but it's actually `mypkg.mymodule.cls`. Using the full path:

```
obj = mypkg.mymodule.cls()
```

avoids the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in Spyder. Turned out to be simple in my case. I defined a class named "Class" in a file also named "Class". I changed the name of the class in the definition to "Class_obj". `pickle.dump(Class_obj,fileh)` works, but `pickle.dump(Class,fileh)` does not when its saved in a file named "Class".

Answer (score 0):

This miraculous function solves the mentioned error, but for me it turned out to another error 'permission denied' which comes out of the blue. However, I guess it might help someone find a solution so I am still posting the function:

```
import tempfile
import time

from tensorflow.keras.models import save_model, Model

# Hotfix function
def make_keras_picklable():
    def __getstate__(self):
        model_str = ""
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.hdf5', delete=True) as fd:
            save_model(self, fd.name, overwrite=True)
            model_str = fd.read()
        d = {'model_str': model_str}
        return d

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.hdf5', delete=True) as fd:
            fd.write(state['model_str'])
            fd.flush()
            model = load_model(fd.name)
        self.__dict__ = model.__dict__


    cls = Model
    cls.__getstate__ = __getstate__
    cls.__setstate__ = __setstate__

# Run the function
make_keras_picklable()

### create then save your model here ###
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47957386/6844235) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1413299/6844235) answers: if you get an error of the form `PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'foo.Bar'>: it's not the same object as foo.Bar`, try replacing `Bar` with `foo.Bar`.

You can use this snippet to try and debug where things go wrong:

```py
from foo import Bar
import foo

print(isinstance(foo.Bar(), foo.Bar)) # True
print(isinstance(Bar(), foo.Bar)) # Sometimes True, sometimes False
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when using a factory pattern with a decorator to produce my objects:

```py
class MyFactory:
    _constructors = {}

    @classmethod
    def register(cls, other):
        cls._constructors[other.__name__] = other

    @classmethod
    def make_from(cls, specification):
        name = specification["name"]
        kwargs = specification["kwargs"]
        return cls._constructors[name](**kwargs)


@MyFactory.register
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, foo=None):
        self._foo = foo


my_obj = MyFactory.make_from({"name": "SomeClass", "kwargs": {"foo": 3}})
print(type(my_obj))
```

This works as expected and yields `<class '__main__.SomeClass'>`

However, I implemented the `register` decorator incorrectly; I should have written it like so:

```py
def register(cls, other):
    cls._constructors[other.__name__] = other
    return other
```

The key that I was missing was to return the original class in the decorator, which manifested with this error. In the case of a class like this, the returned object is the class that actually gets saved at the module level, which in my case was None. I didn't notice this at first, because the factory has cached the class, and all of my code was using the factory to generate these objects. Since `pickle` uses `sys.modules` directly, this error only popped up when I tried to pickle one of the objects from the broken factory.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, my problem came from a decorator, more specifically @lru_cache.
I'd recommend heading to [Pickle and decorated classes (PicklingError: not the same object)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52185507/pickle-and-decorated-classes-picklingerror-not-the-same-object)