# Recursion Depth Exceeded, pickle and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, pickle

I want to pickle html from websites. I save the html to a list and try to pickle it. An example of one such list is the html from brckhmptn.com/tour. Of course the html from this site is a lot, is that my error? The whole script is there but the error is called in the last few lines. I'm using Python 3.6.1

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./showNotifier.py", line 128, in <module>
    scrape_html(combinedUrls)
  File "./showNotifier.py", line 125, in scrape_html
    pickle.dump(sites, hf)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded



#!/home/steph/unix/miniconda3/bin/python
'''
By Stephen Wist
stphnwist@gmail.com
ShowNotifier 
---------------------
script takes cmd line args to:
    indiacte URLS to add
default behaviour is checking if new shows were added
'''
import requests
import pickle 
import sys
import argparse
import os 
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urlFile = "urls"
htmlFile = "htmls"

# take in cmd line args
parseArgs =  argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Add URLs to cache.')
parseArgs.add_argument('urls', type=str, nargs='*', help='URLs to be added.')

# assign cmd line args to urls.urls
urls = parseArgs.parse_args()                                                       

# this function makes sure all files are in place
def status_report():

    # this should be the case only the first time the 
    # script is run
    if (os.path.getsize(urlFile) == 0):
        urlFileExists = 0

        # create urlFile if it does not exist 
        if (not urls.urls):
            print ("No data in the url file. Run the script again but include url(s) on the command line.\n\
        e.g. ./showNotifier.py www.myfavoriteband.com")
            sys.exit()   
    else:
        urlFileExists = 1
    # these file should never be deleted, but just in case
    if (not os.path.isfile(urlFile)):
        f = open("urls","w")
        f.close()
    if (not os.path.isfile(htmlFile)):
        f = open("htmls","w") 
        f.close()
    return urlFileExists
urlFileExists = status_report()


# grab the urls in urlFile, or make
# urlFile if it does not exist
def read_urls(urlFileExists):
    print(urlFileExists)     

    # assign all urls in urlFile to prevUrls
    if (urlFileExists == 1):
        uf = open(urlFile, "rb") 
        prevUrls = pickle.load(uf)
        uf.close()      
        return prevUrls
    else:
        return 1
prevUrls = read_urls(urlFileExists)
print("prevUrls: {}\n".format(prevUrls))


# we will need to check if the user has
# entered a url that is already stored
# and ignore it so the contents of the stored
# urls must be known
def compare_urls(prevUrls, newUrls):

    # no urls were stored in urlFile, 
    # so just move on with the script
    if (prevUrls == 1):
        return newUrls

    # iterate over all urls given on cmd line
    # check for membership in the set of 
    # stored urls and remove them if the
    # test is true
    else:
        for url in newUrls:
            if (url in prevUrls):
                newUrls.remove(url)
                print ("duplicate url {} found, ignoring it.\n".format(url))
        combinedUrls = newUrls + prevUrls
        return combinedUrls
combinedUrls = compare_urls(prevUrls, urls.urls)
print(type(combinedUrls))
print("combinedUrls: {}\n".format(combinedUrls))
print("combo urls[0]: {}\n".format(combinedUrls[0]))
print(type(combinedUrls[0]))


# write all unique urls to file
def write_urls(combinedUrls):
    uf = open(urlFile, "wb") 
    pickle.dump(combinedUrls, uf)
    uf.close()
    return 0
write_urls(combinedUrls)

# TODO: 


# visit sites, store their HTML in a list (for now) 
def scrape_html(combinedUrls):
    sites = []

    # could this loop be shortened to a fancy list comprehension
    # or lambda expression?
    for url in combinedUrls:
        print(url)
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        html = response.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
        sites.append(soup)
    hf = open(htmlFile, "wb")
    pickle.dump(sites, hf)
    hf.close()
    return 0
scrape_html(combinedUrls)
```

Comment: Show the exact error in the question with trace.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134706/hitting-maximum-recursion-depth-using-pickle-cpickle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134706/hitting-maximum-recursion-depth-using-pickle-cpickle) look here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)
```

10 000 recursions should be enough
What happened is that somewhere someplace , something is calling itself over and over again. Each time, thats called one recursion. Python has a limit to prevent a program running infinitely.  While this is usually a sign of an error, you can increase the limit to how you see fit, as your program might recurse for an unusually big amount.

Comment: sorry, i cannot english tonight.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way is to cast soup to a string and then pickle it:

```py
import pickle
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# ... now we have soup
# dump
with open('my_soup.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(str(soup), f)

# load
with open('my_soup.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    str_soup = pickle.load(f)
    re_soup = BeautifulSoup(str_soup, 'lxml')

# check if they are the same

assert soup == re_soup, 'Houston we have a problem'

# we should not see anything if they are the same.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
```

to

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(str(html), "html.parser")
```