# When using multiprocessing and spawn in python, use self.a in __getattr__ cause infinite loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, spawn, getattr

The following code will recurrent the bug:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, set_start_method


class TestObject:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.a = lambda *args: {}

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return self.a

class TestProcess(Process):
    def __init__(self, textobject, **kwargs):
        super(TestProcess, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.testobject = textobject

    def run(self) -> None:
        print("heihei")
        print(self.testobject)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    set_start_method("spawn")

    testobject = TestObject()
    testprocess = TestProcess(testobject)
    testprocess.start()
```

Using 'spawn' will cause infinite loop in the method if 'TestObject.__getattr__'.
When delete the line 'set_start_method('spawn')', all things go right.

It would be very thankful of us to know why the infinite loop happen.

Comment: Which line causes the error? Print `item` to make sure you know which attribute it's looking for. Might surprise you

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348532/can-python-pickle-lambda-functions. Despite lambda functions creating the same type of object as a `def` statement, they *don't* create metadata for the object that `pickle` (used by `multiprocessing`) needs to serialize the object. The restored instance of `TestObject` in the subprocess may not actually have an `a` attribute.

Comment: The item is '__getstate__'. but it is very odd  that only spawn would cause this error @Mad Physicist

Comment: The code is used to show our bug, it has been changed so we can show it as simple as possible. The attr used in ```__getattr__``` should be callable when used in this scenario, so we just use lambda function for simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you head over to pickle's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__setstate__), you will find a note that says

> At unpickling time, some methods like **getattr**(), **getattribute**(), or **setattr**() may be called upon the instance. In case those methods rely on some internal invariant being true, the type should implement **new**() to establish such an invariant, as **init**() is not called when unpickling an instance.

I am unsure of what exact conditions leads to a `__getattribute__` call, but you can bypass the default behaviour by providing a `__setstate__` method:

```
class TestObject:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.a = lambda *args: {}

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return self.a

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.__dict__ = state
```

If it's present, pickle calls this method with the unpickled state and you are free to restore it however you wish.

Comment: Actually, I found a better answer which goes into a little more detail https://stackoverflow.com/a/50158865/16310741

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems work that the infinite loop error dispears, I will see these documents in detail for more description. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Now we figure out what is really happening of the bug:

Before we look into the code, we should know two things:

1. When we define a `__getattr__` method for our class, we should never try to get an attribute that does not belong to the class or the instance itself in `__getattr__`, otherwise it will cause infinite loop, for example:

   ```
   class TestObject:
   def __getattr__(self, item):
       return self.a

   if __name__ == "__main__":
       testobject = TestObject()
       print(f"print a: {testobject.a}")
   ```

   The result should be like this:

   ```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "tmp_test.py", line 10, in <module>
           print(f"print a: {testobject.a}")
       File "tmp_test.py", line 6, in __getattr__
           return self.a
       File "tmp_test.py", line 6, in __getattr__
           return self.a
       File "tmp_test.py", line 6, in __getattr__
           return self.a
       [Previous line repeated 996 more times]
   RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
   ```

   Cause `a` is not in the instance's `__dict__`, so every time it can not find `a`, it will go into the `__getattr__` method and then cause the infinite loop.
2. The next thing we should remember is how the `pickle` module in python
   works. When pickling and unpickling one class's instance, its `dumps` and `loads`(same for `dump` and `load`) function will call the instance's `__getstate__`(for `dumps`) and `__setstate__`(for `loads`) methods. And guess when our class does not define these two methods, where python will look for? Yes, the `__getattr__` method! Normally, it is ok when pickling the instance, cause for this time, the attributes used in `__getattr__` still exist in the instance. But when unpickling, things go wrong.

This is how the `pickle` module documentation says when pickling the class's instance: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickling-class-instances.

And here is what we should notice:
[image]

It means when unpickling one class's instance, **it will not call the `__init__` function to create the instance!** So when unpickling, pickle's `loads` function would check whether the re-instantiate instance has the `__setstate__` method, and as we said above, it will go into the `__getattr__` method, but for now, the attributes that the instance once owned has not been given (at the code `obj.__dict__.update(attributes)`), so bingo, the infinite loop bug appears!

To reproduce the whole exact bug, you can run this code:

```
import pickle


class TestClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.w = 1


class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = TestClass()

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        print(f"{item} begin.")
        print(self.a)
        print(f"{item} end.")
        try:
            return self.a.__getattribute__(item)
        except AttributeError as e:
            raise e

    # def __getstate__(self):
    #     return self.__dict__
    #
    # def __setstate__(self, state):
    #     self.__dict__ = state


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = Test()
    print(test.w)


    test_data = pickle.dumps(test)
    new_test = pickle.loads(test_data)

    print(new_test.w)
```

You should get the infinite bug when not add the `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` method, and add them will fix it. You can also try to see the `print info` to see whether the bug exists at `__getattr__('__setstate__')`.

And the connection between this  `pickle` bug and our `multiprocessing` bug at beginning is that it seems when using `spawn``, the son process's context would try to pickle the father process's context and then unpickle it and inherit it. So now all things make sense.