# How to save the BeautifulSoup object to a file and then read from it as BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to save the BeautifulSoup object to a file. So, I change it into a string, then write it to a file. Then after reading it as a string, I convert the string into a BeautifulSoup object. This would help during my testing as the data I am scraping is dynamic.

```py
url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/all/views/all/"
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
```

Writing the soup object like this:

```py
  new_soup = str(soup)
  with open("coin.txt", "w+") as f:
      f.write(new_soup)
```

produces this error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode 
characters in position 28127-28132: character maps to <undefined>
```

Also, if I am able to save it to a file, how would I read the string returned as a BeautifulSoup object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use pickle to save a dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218477/how-can-i-use-pickle-to-save-a-dict)

Comment: you are doing terrible something. you better save the html instead

Answer (score 5):

## EDIT

The old code couldn't pickle the `soup` object due to `RecursionError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "soup.py", line 20, in <module>
    pickle.dump(soup, f)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

The solution is to [increase the recursion limit](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/31/fixing-error-maximum-recursion-depth-reached/). They do the same in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2135176/5535114), which in turn, references the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled).

**HOWEVER**, the particular site you're trying to load and save is *extremely* nested. My computer can't get past a recursion of limit of 50000 and it's not enough for your site and crashes: `10008 segmentation fault (core dumped)  python soup.py`.

So, if you need to download the HTML and use it later you can do this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/all/views/all/"
html = urlopen(url)

# Save HTML to a file
with open("soup.html", "wb") as f:
    while True:
        chunk = html.read(1024)
        if not chunk:
            break
        f.write(chunk)
```

Then you can read the HTML file you saved and instantiate the bs4 object with it:

```
# Read HTML from a file
with open("soup.html", "rb") as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), "lxml")

print(soup.title)
# <title>All Cryptocurrencies | CoinMarketCap</title>
```

Additionally, this is the code I would use for a less nested site:

```
import pickle
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import sys

url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52973700/how-to-save-the-beautifulsoup-object-to-a-file-and-then-read-from-it-as-beautifu"
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")

sys.setrecursionlimit(8000)

# Save the soup object to a file
with open("soup.pickle", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(soup, f)

# Read the soup object from a file
with open("soup.pickle", "rb") as f:
    soup_obj = pickle.load(f)

print(soup_obj.title)

# <title>python - How to save the BeautifulSoup object to a file and then read from it as BeautifulSoup? - Stack Overflow</title>.
```

Comment: I get `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while pickling an object`
when I run this code, because of the object is huge.

Comment: I too get 'Recursion error: maximum depth exceeded' error

Comment: You're both right. I edited my answer. Turns out the resulting soup object is too nested to pickle it, but there are workarounds.