# multiprocessing manager fails pickling

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am implementing a random forest algorithm for a school assignment, to make it faster im using multiprocessing where each process creates a tree, these trees are limited to a certain depth, say 200 or 500.

The trees are stored in a dictionary defined like this:

```
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
return_dict = manager.dict()
```

When I run the algorithm with depth 200 it works just fine, but at 500 the multiprocessing library produces an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\agust\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\agust\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\agust\PycharmProjects\tarea2\random_forest.py", line 27, in id3_aux
    return_dict[index] = nodo_res
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "C:\Users\agust\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 834, in _callmethod
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
  File "C:\Users\agust\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "C:\Users\agust\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while pickling an object
```

If I undestand correctly, it can't pickle the tree because it's too deep. Is there any way to increase the recursion limit for pickling, or store the trees in a different way to prevent this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hitting Maximum Recursion Depth Using Pickle / cPickle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134706/hitting-maximum-recursion-depth-using-pickle-cpickle)

Comment: with sys.setrecursionlimit(1000000) it still gives the same error, any way i can check what recursion depth it fails at?