# Is it possible to tune parameters with grid search for custom kernels in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a custom kernel function, and I am using GridSearchCV function with SVC(kernel=my_kernel).

my_kernel function takes a parameter k to tune, so I was wondering whether it's possible to configure param_grid option to tune the parameter of my custom kernel function.

For example, it's possible to tune gamma parameter for RBF kernel as follows. Can I provide a param_grid=dict(k=k_range) kind of option for my custom kernel?

```
gamma_range = 10. ** np.arange(-5, 4)
param_grid = dict(gamma=gamma_range)
grid = GridSearchCV(SVC(), param_grid=param_grid, cv=StratifiedKFold(y=Y, k=5))
```

Answer (score 12):

One way to do this is using `Pipeline`, `SVC(kernel='precomputed')` and wrapping your custom kernel function as a `sklearn` estimator (a subclass of `BaseEstimator` and `TransformerMixin`)).

For example, `sklearn` contains a [custom kernel function](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.chi2_kernel.html) `chi2_kernel(X, Y=None, gamma=1.0)`, which computes the kernel matrix of feature vectors `X` and `Y`.
This function takes a parameter `gamma`, which should preferably be set using cross-validation.
We can do grid search on the parameters of this function as follows:

```python
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import division

import sys

import numpy as np

import sklearn
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import chi2_kernel
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.svm import SVC

# Wrapper class for the custom kernel chi2_kernel
class Chi2Kernel(BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, gamma=1.0):
        super(Chi2Kernel,self).__init__()
        self.gamma = gamma

    def transform(self, X):
        return chi2_kernel(X, self.X_train_, gamma=self.gamma)

    def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        self.X_train_ = X
        return self

def main():

    print('python: {}'.format(sys.version))
    print('numpy: {}'.format(np.__version__))
    print('sklearn: {}'.format(sklearn.__version__))
    np.random.seed(0)

    # Get some data to evaluate
    dataset = load_digits()
    X = dataset.data
    y = dataset.target
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33)

    # Create a pipeline where our custom predefined kernel Chi2Kernel
    # is run before SVC.
    pipe = Pipeline([
        ('chi2', Chi2Kernel()),
        ('svm', SVC()),
    ])

    # Set the parameter 'gamma' of our custom kernel by
    # using the 'estimator__param' syntax.
    cv_params = dict([
        ('chi2__gamma', 10.0**np.arange(-9,4)),
        ('svm__kernel', ['precomputed']),
        ('svm__C', 10.0**np.arange(-2,9)),
    ])

    # Do grid search to get the best parameter value of 'gamma'.
    model = GridSearchCV(pipe, cv_params, cv=5, verbose=1, n_jobs=-1)
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
    acc_test = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)

    print("Test accuracy: {}".format(acc_test))
    print("Best params:")
    print(model.best_params_)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
    python: 2.7.3 (default, Dec 18 2014, 19:10:20)
    [GCC 4.6.3]
    numpy: 1.8.0
    sklearn: 0.16.1
    Fitting 5 folds for each of 143 candidates, totalling 715 fits
    [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   1 jobs       | elapsed:    0.4s
    [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  50 jobs       | elapsed:    2.7s
    [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done 200 jobs       | elapsed:    9.8s
    [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done 450 jobs       | elapsed:   21.6s
    [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done 701 out of 715 | elapsed:   34.8s remaining:    0.7s
    [Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done 715 out of 715 | elapsed:   35.4s finished
    Test accuracy: 0.989898989899
    Best params:
    {'chi2__gamma': 0.01, 'svm__C': 10.0, 'svm__kernel': 'precomputed'}
```

In your case, just replace `chi2_kernel` with your function that computes the kernel matrix.

Comment: I'm trying to implement the [Epanechnikov kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(statistics)#Kernel_functions_in_common_use) using Tommi's example. I keep getting this error: 

`PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'epanechnikov_kernel.EpanechnikovKernel'>: it's not the same object as epanechnikov_kernel.EpanechnikovKernel`

Another [StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412787/picklingerror-cant-pickle-class-decimal-decimal-its-not-the-same-object) suggests turning off `%load_ext autoreload` `autoreload 2`, but I still get this error. 

Ideas?

Comment: you may find the `dill` package handles serializing nonstandard / custom transforms better than other pickling methods

Answer (score 1):

with scikit-learn 0.19, you can do

```
from sklearn.kernel_ridge import KernelRidge
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import chi2_kernel

reg_kridge=KernelRidge(kernel='chi2')
params_grid={"gamma":np.logspace(0,-4,5)}
reg=GridSearchCV(reg_kridge,params_grid, n_jobs=-1,cv=10,scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
reg.fit(train, target)
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43470610/how-to-tune-parameters-of-custom-kernel-function-with-pipeline-in-scikit-learn/44277799#44277799)...  how about using an automated parameter tuning with [auto-sklearn](https://automl.github.io/auto-sklearn)? It is a drop-in replacement of sklearn and frequently it does a better job than manually tuned parameters.