# How to reload python module in flask?

Tags: python, flask

I have a file called `mapping.py` which has a dictionary `methodMapping`. In my web application, a key-value pair is added to the methodMapping dictionary. After I appended it to `mapping.py`, `reload(mapping)` is called, and the file reloads (I checked by printing out a message on top of the file), but when I try to access the key-value pair, `KeyError` is raised.

original mapping.py file:

```
print('mapping.py loaded) methodMapping =  {} 
methodMapping['key1'] = 'value1'
```

here is how the key-value pair is appended to the file:

```
from mapping import methodMapping
@app.route('/append', methods=['POST'])
def append():

    key = request.form.get('key')
    value = request.form.get('value')

    value = value.encode('ascii', 'ignore')

    f = open('mapping.py', 'a')
    f.write('methodMapping["'+key+'"] = '+value)
    f.write("\n\n")
    f.close()

    reload(mapping)
    return ....
```

after a key-value is added, mapping.py looks like this:

```
print('mapping.py loaded') 
methodMapping =  {} 
methodMapping['key1'] = 'value1'
methodMapping['key2'] = 'value2'
```

however, when I try to access `methodMapping['key2']` from flaskServer.py, `KeyError` exception is raised. When I restart the server, it is able to find `methodMapping['key2']`.

Note: I have already checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344756/auto-reloading-python-flask-app-upon-code-changes) also tried `app.run(debug=True, port=8000)`, but this is not possible for my application because I'm using keras with Tensorflow backend, and setting debug=True will load it twice and leads to a `ValueError: Tensor tensor(...) is not part of the graph` error

Any comment or suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I found the solution: The problem was from the way I imported mapping. If I want `reload(mapping)` to work, I need to use `import mapping` instead of `from mapping import ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the way you imported mapping.  If you want `reload(mapping)` to work, you need to use `import mapping` instead of `from mapping import...`.

And if you find the answer, you should put it in an Answer instead of in a comment. ;)

Comment: Thank you for the comment - I'll check yours as the answer then :) Also, I have another problem which is after the reload(), I am unable to use pickle because, according to this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412787/picklingerror-cant-pickle-class-decimal-decimal-its-not-the-same-object  it needs to be in the form `from mapping import...` for pickle to work. Do you perhaps know the answer to that?

Comment: According to that answer you just have to import things the same way each time, not a particular way.