# Python multiprocessing decorator fails at pickling

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

My use case: I want a `fire and forget` function decorator, which will just asynchronously call another function.

Here's what I have right now:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def fire_and_forget(func):
   def inner(*args, **kwargs):
      proc = Process(target=func, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
      proc.start()
      proc.join()
   return inner
```

Simple enough -- a typical python decorator that just creates a new process for the function and starts it. I believe this will give me the async functionality I'm looking for.

Now, I decorate a test function with this:

```
@fire_and_forget
def my_test_function(name, age=24):
   print(f'Name: {name}, Age: {age}')

my_test_function('John')
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    my_test_function('John')
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 4, in inner
    proc.start()
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 112, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 89, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function my_test_function at 0x03C93810>: it's not the same object as __main__.my_test_function
```

I have seen some articles explaining that this is a pickling issue, but I haven't been able to fully understand what is going on here.
I don't want to switch to not using a decorator, but I am open to using something other than the multiprocessing library.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. This answer suggests execution environment can be an issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412787/picklingerror-cant-pickle-class-decimal-decimal-its-not-the-same-object and this post suggests macos problem https://discuss.python.org/t/is-multiprocessing-broken-on-macos-in-python-3-8/4969. Works for me on Ubuntu16.04

Comment: Indent the latter snippet and put it inside an `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard.

Comment: "I believe this will give me the async functionality I'm looking for." -- `.join()` blocks, though. So instead of asynchronous, you'll practically doing it synchronously.