# _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function unzip at 0x7ff3e899c1f0>: it's not the same object as endpoints.v1.s3.unzip

Tags: multiprocessing, pickle

When running linux code on a local mac environment, I am encountering the following error associated with decorator functions and multiprocessing. I am running Python 3.8.10.

```
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function unzip at 0x7ff3e899c1f0>: it's not the same object as endpoints.v1.s3.unzip
```

I am also using functools.wraps, which does not appear to help with this issue.

Comment: Can you provide your code that's causing the error?

Comment: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53869959/3220135) the general cause of the problem (Conflicting namespace; often when something gets re-named as happens with `@wraps`). If you can share some of your code we may be able to provide more specific help.